# jenkins plugin installation with and without restart difference

Tags: jenkins, plugins, build, release, devops

What is difference between installation jenkins plugin  with restart and without restart.

Can I install a plugin with restart when other builds are running?.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between 'with restart' and 'without restart' plugin installation is that you cannot upgrade or uninstall plugins without restart (because of the architectural choice made in Jenkins).

So, new plugin can be installed without restart (and when other builds are running as well).

For details, see the official [post](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/install-plugins-without-restarting-jenkins) from Kohsuke Kawaguchi's blog.